# Java: how to determine the type of drive a file is located on?

Tags: java, drive

Is there a platform-independent way with Java to detect the type of drive a file is located on? Basically I'm interested to distinguish between: **hard disks**, **removable drives** (like USB sticks) and **network shares**. JNI/JNA solutions won't be helpful. Java 7 can be assumed.

Comment: Perhaps it might be simpler to solve why you want to know this?

Comment: I need that information to warn users about certain drawbacks of the underlying file system: performance, file system monitoring won't work, things like that.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542018/how-can-i-get-list-of-all-drives-but-also-get-the-corresponding-drive-type-remo/17972420#17972420
I am using WMI to access the desired information.

Answer (score 5):

You could execute cmd using Java with:

```
fsutil fsinfo drivetype {drive letter}
```

The result will give you something like this:

```
C: - Fixed Drive
D: - CD-ROM Drive
E: - Removable Drive
P: - Remote/Network Drive
```

Comment: It's not platform-independent and fsutil even seems to require administrative privileges.

Comment: I found this code very helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678363/find-the-directory-for-a-filestore

Comment: me too (very helpful)

Answer (score 4):

The [`FileSystemView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html) class from Swing has *some* functionality to support detecting the type of the drive (cf `isFloppyDrive`, `isComputerNode`). I'm afraid there's no standard way to detect if a drive is connected through USB though.

Contrived, untested example:

```
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
....
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
FileSystemView fsv = fc.getFileSystemView();
if (fsv.isFloppyDrive(new File("A:"))) // is A: a floppy drive?
```

In JDK 7 there's another option. I haven't used it, but the `FileStore` API has a `type` method. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileStore.html#type%28%29) says that:

> The format of the string returned by this method is highly implementation specific. It may indicate, for example, the format used or if the file store is local or remote.

Apparently the way to use it would be this:

```
import java.nio.*;
....
for (FileStore store: FileSystems.getDefault().getFileStores()) {
    System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", store.name(), store.type());
}
```

Comment: FileSystemView.isFloppyDrive() is implemented by something like "path.equals("A:\\")" what unfortunately won't be helpful. Also, I didn't find FileStore.type() helpful. It returns "NTFS" for my network shares.

Comment: FileStore#type() returns "NTFS" for network drives on Windows 7, Java 7.

Comment: FileStore#type() returns "NTFS" for local hard drives on Windows 10, too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Gist which shows how to determine this using `net use`: https://gist.github.com/digulla/31eed31c7ead29ffc7a30aaf87131def

Most important part of the code:

```
    public boolean isDangerous(File file) {
        if (!IS_WINDOWS) {
            return false;
        }

        // Make sure the file is absolute
        file = file.getAbsoluteFile();
        String path = file.getPath();
//        System.out.println("Checking [" + path + "]");

        // UNC paths are dangerous
        if (path.startsWith("//")
            || path.startsWith("\\\\")) {
            // We might want to check for \\localhost or \\127.0.0.1 which would be OK, too
            return true;
        }

        String driveLetter = path.substring(0, 1);
        String colon = path.substring(1, 2);
        if (!":".equals(colon)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected 'X:': " + path);
        }

        return isNetworkDrive(driveLetter);
    }

    /** Use the command <code>net</code> to determine what this drive is.
     * <code>net use</code> will return an error for anything which isn't a share.
     * 
     *  <p>Another option would be <code>fsinfo</code> but my gut feeling is that
     *  <code>net</code> should be available and on the path on every installation
     *  of Windows.
     */
    private boolean isNetworkDrive(String driveLetter) {
        List<String> cmd = Arrays.asList("cmd", "/c", "net", "use", driveLetter + ":");

        try {
            Process p = new ProcessBuilder(cmd)
                .redirectErrorStream(true)
                .start();

            p.getOutputStream().close();

            StringBuilder consoleOutput = new StringBuilder();

            String line;
            try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    consoleOutput.append(line).append("\r\n");
                }
            }

            int rc = p.waitFor();
//            System.out.println(consoleOutput);
//            System.out.println("rc=" + rc);
            return rc == 0;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to run 'net use' on " + driveLetter, e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this discussion: [How can I get list of all drives but also get the corresponding drive type (removable,local disk, or cd-rom,dvd-rom... etc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542018/how-can-i-get-list-of-all-drives-but-also-get-the-corresponding-drive-type-remo)

Specifically pay attention on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html

I personally have not used this but it seems relevant. It has method like is `isFloppyDrive`.

Also take a look on [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/docs/jniapi/jsmooth/DriveInfo.html)

Comment: FileSystemView won't work. JSmooth might work, though I was hoping to find some API which ships with the JRE itself.