# Java nio WatchService: Watch Windows drives list

Tags: java, windows, nio, watchservice

I want to get notified, when an USB-Drive is connected. So that java sais: "Drive H: created".
Is there a way to do this with the WatchService? Watching the root-directory doesn't work. It just watches the root of the current drive:
    Paths.get("/").register

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do that with a `WatchService`. Since you are only worried about Windows, you can simply poll [`FileSystem.getRootDirectories`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getRootDirectories%28%29) and detect changes.

```
try {
   List<Path> roots = asList(FileSystems.getDefault().getRootDirectories());
   for(;;) {
        Thread.sleep(500);

        List<Path> newRoots = asList(FileSystems.getDefualt().getRootDirectories());
        for(Path newRoot : newRoots){
            if(!roots.contains(newRoot)) {
                System.out.println("New drive detected: " + newRoot);
            }
        }
        roots = newRoots;
    }
} catch(InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

If you wanted this to work on other operating systems, you would have to poll [`FileSystem.getFileStores`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getFileStores%28%29) and figure out a way to [get the root path for a `FileStore`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10678363/758280).

/e1

```
private <T> List<T> asList(Iterable<T> i) {
    if (i instanceof List) { return (List<T>) i; }

    List<T> l = new ArrayList<>();
    for (T t : i) {
        l.add(t);
    }
    return l;
}
```

Comment: What's the `asList` method?

Comment: I believe this was a modified snippet of code I wrote a while ago. `asList` converts an `Iterable` to a `List`, I'll edit it in.