# List all connected devices of the certain type (cameras, drives etc.)

Tags: java, device-driver

My question is rather essential, but it seems to be difficult one enough. I need to list all connected devices and to sort them into groups (eg. cameras, disks). And these devices should be not only external (USB, COM, PS/2), but also built-in ones. For example, I need to detect all cameras. So the expected resul is:

```
0 - ASUS Webcam USB 2.0
1 - Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920
```

How can I do this? Could you advise some libraries for this?

Comment: Do you mean that your Java code should *detect* them?

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes, and if it possible to detect just plugged ones(I mean to detect devices at once after connecting)

Comment: For what platform? Remember that Java runs in `JVM` that is implemented on many devices with different OS.

Comment: Look at answers to this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542018/how-can-i-get-list-of-all-drives-but-also-get-the-corresponding-drive-type-remo).

Comment: @PM77-1 It's not that I meant. I need to find ALL devices. The method that you advised me can find only devices which can be adressed by letter. The other ones (for example built-in cameras, connected phones) couldn't be accessed by such way.

Comment: This is still better than nothing.  What you need is most likely impossible to have platform independent.  [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606820/is-there-a-java-library-to-access-the-native-windows-api) talks about Java access to Windows APIs. Since Windows has all this information (as shown in My Computer) it should be possible to retrieve it.  So to answer your question:  Yes, is possible. It will require a lot of research on your part.

Comment: @PM77-1 Of course, I understand that it's impossible to make app platform independent. Well, I rephrase my question: do you know some methods or libraries to detect such devices?

Comment: No, I do not.  I would expect them to be mostly for Android these days.