# detect external hard disk and sandisk cruzer blade 16 GB as removable in java

Tags: java

i am trying to print drive letters and their system type. In this program it prints hard disk drives as logical drive, cd drives as cd drive, Memory card as Removable Drive. When I plugged in External Hard disk and a pendrive (sandisk cruzer blade 16 GB) it shows both as a logical drive. I want to detect and print external hard disk and that pendrive as 'removable device' as they are portable. Please help me how to do it.
Here is the code.

```
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
import java.io.File;
public static void main(String x[])
{
    File paths[];
    paths = File.listRoots();
    for(File path: pahts)
    {
            System.out.println("Drive Name: "+path);
            System.out.println("Description: "+fsv.getSystemTypeDescription(path));


    }



}
```

Comment: OS specific commands usually require you to call a command line utility to get this information.  I suggest you find out how you can do this from the command line.

Comment: see this one http://jusb.sourceforge.net/apidoc/usb/core/USBListener.html

Comment: @shadi375, The project referred by you is not working. i download the source code and compile it in netbeans and as described in documentation of this project 'foo' class contains the swing interface with all the basic information of USB to be displayed on its run but its giving the error of 'USB Host support is unavailable'

Comment: @weston please include one line FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView(); before the loop and then compile and run it. it will display all the drive letters and their type in command line.

Comment: Hmm. My ScanDisk Cruzer "E:" is displaying "Removable Disk" using similar code to yours:

    C:\ [Local Disk]
    D:\ [CD Drive]
    E:\ [Removable Disk]
    G:\ [Local Disk]
    H:\ [Local Disk]
    I:\ [Local Disk]

Comment: @user2299040 From [jUSB](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/?selected=types):

"Although the bulk of this code works on any Java platform, access to USB devices currently requires that they be connected to a GNU/Linux host system."

Are you running on Windows?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542018/how-can-i-get-list-of-all-drives-but-also-get-the-corresponding-drive-type-remo for some possibilites

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes I am running my program on windows environment. That is why USB host support is unavailable like you stated in your comment. The thing is the same can be done using visual studio but as you know that makes the program run only on windows platform. I want my program to be platform independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OS specific commands and execute it via java `Runtime`. For example in windows you could use the command [wmic](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx) to get all the drive details like device name, caption, file system, type etc. For example `wmic logicaldisk get deviceid driveType` will list all the avilable drive letters and their types. The logical disk has 7 drive types

```
0 = Unknown
1 = No Root Directory
2 = Removable Disk
3 = Local Disk
4 = Network Drive
5 = Compact Disc
6 = RAM Disk
```

As you could see type 2 is the one you are looking for. Apart from logicaldisk details wmic could be used to retrieve all aspects of system like cpu, bios etc. A list of all commands in wmic could be found [here](http://www.computerhope.com/wmic.htm).

Similarly you have [udevadm](http://linux.die.net/man/8/udevadm) command in linux to get device details and [system_profiler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/system_profiler.8.html) in Mac. So if you want a plantform independent way of accessing details you could change the command based on current OS. Use `System.getProperty("os.name")` to idetify the current OS.

A sample program for windows OS

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class DriveDetails {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String command = "wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=$$ get deviceid";
        for (DriveType driveType : DriveType.values()) {
            String query = command.replace("$$", String.valueOf(driveType.getType()));
            System.out.println(driveType.getDescription());
            System.out.println(executeCommand(query).trim());
        }
    }

    private static String executeCommand(String command) {
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        Process p = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    p.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            boolean flag = true;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if(flag) {
                    flag = false;
                    continue; // Skipping header
                }
                output.append(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (p != null)
                p.destroy();
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return output.toString();
    }

    enum DriveType {
        UNKNOWN(0, "Unknown"),
        NO_ROOT_DIRECTORY(1, "No Root Directory"),
        REMOVABLE_DISK(2, "Removable Disk"),
        LOCAL_DISK(3, "Local Disk"),
        NETWORK_DRIVE(4, "Network Drive"),
        COMPACT_DISC(5, "Compact Disc"),
        RAM_DISK(6, "RAM Disk");

        private DriveType(int type, String description) {
            this.type = type;
            this.description = description;
        }

        private int type;
        private String description;

        public int getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(int type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: :) First thanks a lot for introducing me with WMI.I will make programs to work with wmi commands but have you tried your sample program?! I ran the program and it just got struck in 'unknown' nothing else is shown. I waited for almost 10 minutes but still it displays only 'unknown'. but anyways thanks a lot

Comment: It works fine for me. That might be the issue with runtime. I didn't handle the error stream. Can you try that command in command prompt and see if you have proper privileges?

Comment: the command works fine :) there was a issue in java runtime.. some kind of bug..when i reinstall it. your code works.