# How to check "if a flash drive is plugged in" and copy the data thereby in JAVA

Tags: java

I want to check by program if a flash drive (pen drive) is plugged into my computer. If I can detect that a flash drive is plugged in then all the contents will be copied to my computer invisibly. I've a idea to do that. But I think it's pretty bad.

```
String allDrives[] = {"A","B",....,"Z"};
while(true){
   for(String drive : allDrives){
      if(drive exists){
          Do the required task
      }   
   }
}
```

Is there any better idea to do that? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please try searching harder first to avoid duplicate questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get list of all drives but also get the corresponding drive type (removable,local disk, or cd-rom,dvd-rom... etc)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542018/how-can-i-get-list-of-all-drives-but-also-get-the-corresponding-drive-type-remo). Technically isn't a dupe, since no one has asked this exact question. However, it shows no research effort at all, and the questions that appear are very related.

Answer (score 0):

Use the proper way to [list drives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542018/how-can-i-get-list-of-all-drives-but-also-get-the-corresponding-drive-type-remo), then [copy the files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106770/standard-concise-way-to-copy-a-file-in-java), maybe someone with more points can close this as a duplicate.